# Mediawiki lets me login but redirects to login page again instead of main page

Tags: redirect, authentication, mediawiki

we have a MediaWiki installation successfully running. It is set up so that every user has to login with username and password before being able to read or edit anything. This works fine, if the main page is accessed and the user is not logged in yet, the login page is shown.

However, after logging in, the user is not redirected to the main page but sees the login page again. If one now enters the main page manually into the browser address, one can access the page, so the user is actually successfully loggged in. If one logs in again, one gets the error message, that one is already logged in.

Does anybody have an idea of how to resolve this strange behaviour? I would like the user to be redirected to the main page or any other page that he/she requested after successfully loggin in.

Thanks and best regards. Any help appreciated since I was not able to find any helpfuls hints/similar problems on google or stackoverflow.

Stephan

Comment: To clarify:
- I request the page: index.php?title=Main_Page
- I am shown "Login required", please log in to view other pages. I need to click on the link to "log in"
- I am sent to index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main+Page and shown "Log in". I need to enter username and password and click on the button "Log in".
- I am sent to index.php?title=Main_Page but still shown "Login required", Please log in to view other pages. If I click on the reload button in the browser, I am actually being served the correct contents of the Main_Page without having to to anything else.

Comment: Wrong cache settings? Try disabling the cache on your browser + file cache on the wiki and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is enough disk space. I remember of a similar problem related to a lack of disk space. The behaviour I encountered was similar to what you describe, but I can not remember the exact content of the URLs in that case. So check your file system. It might be the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the disk space, but there should be plenty. I have no clue of how to tackle the problem. Does anybody have an idea of what to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you already have looked into the log for some hints and found nothing. Have you performed a HTTP protocol dump of your problem? You might get a hint this way. Are you running the latest version of media wiki? If not I would suggest to dump the database and perform an upgrade to the latest version. If something is messed up you might get it fixed automatically that way. If you can not figure it out what is wrong this might be some kind of fallback attempt for you. I run several Wikis and absolutely never run into that problem. And I'm dealing with Wikis for years now!

Comment: Thank you. I have set up log files and activated the log bar (even if I did not have the knowledge to read anything meaningful out of the logged data). In addition, I have updated to 1.25.2. Did not solve the problem. However, I solved the issue partially: When activating the option "keep me logged ", I am sent directly to the originally desired page (however, that button is by default always unchecked for me). If I don't select that button, I am first sent to the "Login required" page again and need to click on "log in" to be sent directly to where I wanted to go originally. Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to help: I would require to see your problem in action and have access to the machine. But I have one more idea: Dive into the PHP code. It's not that difficult. Insert log statements into the PHP code where necessary. Track down the problem this way: You might come across something this way. I do not recommend patching the code because it is hard to keep track of your patch over updates. I do that with the SMW extensions because there is a show stopping bug in them but I generally advice NOT to do something like that. Nevertheless you could at least understand what is going on.

Comment: A simple output statement that writes log data to a temporary file might be enough. Move the statement further down some 'if'-branches as necessary to better understand what is going on. Then you can understand if this is a bug or a feature or just a matter of misconfiguration. Hope that idea helps!